# Android Studio 2.0. Changes in code dont take effect

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making many changes in the code of my app, but when I run the code the changes are not in place, unless i rebuild the project and then run it, which is a slow process.
What could it be?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry to ask, but why did my question get a minus? I have been struggling with this, and not succeeding.

Comment: Because your question is badly written. If you have instant run active, it's probably a bug of that. You're not the first to have problems like this one with instant run, so do a Google search before posting to stackoverflow.

Comment: a) Disable instant run. If that doesn't work b) Use build plugin 1.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

This  is because of instant run..

you need to turn off Instant Run, go to **Settings → Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run** and **uncheck Enable Instant Run**.

I too had the same problem this solution worked for me.